# Как картинку поставить  вверх таблицы?

Tags: html, css, javascript

Привет.

У меня вот такой вопрос. Как картинку поставить вверх таблицы, так чтобы она скрыла  линии (border) и не меняла место при увеличении или уменьшении масштаба страницы, или хоть не меняла место при разных мониторах (квадрат)?

Я делал с помощью

```
position: absolute;
padding-top: 680px; 
padding-left: 770px;
```

Но оно блокирует все нижние элементы и не работает скрипт `onMouseOver` и  `onClick`...

Заранее спасибо! :)

Answer (score 2):

может проще border убрать, а картинку фоном поставить без дублирования фона по x и y?

```
<table border="0" background="ссылка на картинку" style="background-repeat:no-repeat">
<tr>
 <td width="500" height="500">&nbsp;
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: А какой код для этого нужно? border и так я убираю, просто разные фоны у `<td>`, поэтому хочу разницу между фонами скрыть картинкой!

Comment: Выше пример добавил.

Comment: если делать через position:absolute, то элементы необходимо разместить на нужных слоях, где высота слоя задается через z-index

подробнее о слоях можно прочитать например тут http://dreamhelg.ru/2009/09/css-property-z-index/

Comment: ах вы это имели введу, это тут не к чему, каждая <td>  имеет одну фон ( в одном тень вертикальной  а в другом по горизонтальной )

Comment: тогда я не понял что вообще нужно. пример в студию